# Meteor not server .JS for <script> in <template>

Tags: meteor

In app.html:

```
<body>
  {{> index}}
</body>

<template name="index">
...
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/swiffy/v5.2/runtime.js" type="text/javascript" />
<script src="animation.js" type="text/javascript" />
...
</template>
```

`animation.js` is inside /public along with all the html and jpeg's etc for a static site.

When I navigate to the app root, it all works right except that the [Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) animation just doesn't show up.  Perhaps something to do with Meteor not just serving JS from the /public directory? How can I fix this?

When I navigate to the very same code stored as /public/index.html, the animation shows up.

Note: [Swiffy](https://www.google.com/doubleclick/studio/swiffy/) is just a way to automatically convert Flash animations into .JS that is run by the Swiffy runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Client JS libraries should be placed in the client directory. This will make it available to meteor for inclusion into the minified app.

For more information see http://docs.meteor.com/#structuringyourapp

Answer (score 0):

You can put your library to /client/compatibility directory. But you put there, all pages include your library. If you want some pages include your javascript you must use ext package. For example https://atmosphere.meteor.com/package/external-file-loader